# Put a picture on a full page

Tags: graphics, geometry, includegraphics

I want to include a picture, so that it covers 100% of the page. From edge to edge, no white spaces, just the picture. I use A4 paper (European style) and the picture has also A4 format, so that should not be a problem.

The goal I want:

- one page: full with the picture
- next page: just another small picture

let´s call the picture xx (big) and yy (small). My concern is ONLY with xx

I have this MWE

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrreprt}

\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\pagestyle{empty}
\parindent0pt

\begin{document}

    
\newgeometry{left=0mm, right=0mm, top=0mm, bottom=0mm}
\includegraphics[width=.999\textwidth,height=.999\textheight,keepaspectratio]{xx}

\newgeometry{left=10mm, right=10mm, top=10mm, bottom=10mm}
\includegraphics[width=12cm]{yy}    

\newgeometry{left=0mm, right=0mm, top=0mm, bottom=0mm}
\includegraphics[width=1\textwidth,height=1\textheight,keepaspectratio]{xx}

\newgeometry{left=10mm, right=10mm, top=10mm, bottom=10mm}
\includegraphics[width=8cm]{yy}

\end{document}
```

The problem with the first picture is, that there is a small, but anoying whit line on the right and lower edge. The problem with the second big picture is, that there is a empty page produced before the actual page with the picture. But I do not know why. What can I do?

This is the picture I use (as xx), yy picture I realy do not care, it is not a problem.

[image]

Comment: If you happen to have a pdf version of your image, you could use the `pdfpages` package to include it as a complete page.

Comment: Thank you for BOTH of you solutions, the are very helpful :)
I guess I use tikz, because I fear I loose some quality in the picture, if I convert the pgf to a pdf file

I a guess that tikz is not overkill, if you define a newcommand. Then it is handy to use :)

Comment: TikZ is a very powerful, but also a very large package. It takes comparatively long to load the package, but if that's not a problem for you, I'd say enjoy: the easy solution :)

Comment: Thank you for the advice. You say if I compile the file it takes longer, if TikZ is used?

Comment: exactly, not a lot, but for some people the speed is important.

Comment: thank you for the input. Just another question. Is the speed already decreasing, when ```tikz``` as a package is in the preamble or only if I actually use it in the document?

Comment: Yes, it consists of many files, so loading it takes longer than other packages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Might be a bit overkill, but if you would use TikZ to position your image, you wouldn't have to worry about changing page geometries back and forth.

If you want to exactly fill the page, I would ditch the `keepaspectratio` option. Your image might be slightly distorted, but you won't get white edges if the image does not have exactly the correct size.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrreprt}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay,inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt]
\node at (current page.center) {\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{example-image-duck}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\clearpage

next page

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

1.0 Use only `height=\pageheight` if you dont want it to eject a spurious page. Your image must have the same aspect ratio as the page, if you do not want to have a distorted image.

2.0 Put the image in a 0pt box and position at the center of the page with Tikz or use the shipout hook from LaTeX2e and position with `picture`.

3.0 If you set geometry to 0pt for all margins you can use:

```
\newpage
\ExplSyntaxOn
\dim_set:Nn\l_tmpa_dim{\paperwidth/2}
\hspace*{\l_tmpa_dim}\makebox[0pt]{\includegraphics[height=\paperheight]{example-image-duck}}
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

or simply `\hspace*{105mm}` which is half of `\pagewidth`, this solution does not require Tikz.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\null     % leave a blank to view double page in pdf viewer
\newpage  %
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay,inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt]
\node at (current page.center) {\makebox[0pt]{\includegraphics[height=\paperheight]{example-image-duck}}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\newpage
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay,inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt]
\node at (current page.center) {\makebox[0pt]{\includegraphics[height=\paperheight]{roots}}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\newpage
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay,inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt]
\node at (current page.center) {\makebox[0pt]{\includegraphics[width=\paperheight]{roots}}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\newpage
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay,inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt]
\node at (current page.center) {\makebox[0pt]{\includegraphics[width=\paperheight,height=\paperheight]{roots}}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```